# Can I use 'whatever' in this sentence? Why is 'what' here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, pronouns

> The rising power of the consumer and their new-found ability to **get what they want**, whenever they want, from whomever they want.

1."to get what they want"
Can I use 'whatever' instead?

2.What' s the grammar functions of 'whenever' clause and 'whomever' clause here?

Answer (score 1):

For parallelism it should be either “whatever ... whenever ... whomever” or “what ... when ... whom”.

The -ever forms are a bit stronger, but both are variants of the same fixed phrase with the sense that *anything is possible*.

The three w’s aren’t separate clauses; they are separated by commas purely for readability and emphasis, with pauses when speaking, and that’s part of the fixed phrase as well.

Comment: I agree with most of what you way, but “what they want.” “whenever they want” and “whomever they want” are all clauses. They each have their own subject and verb, as well as a direct object. In this sentence, the clause “what[ever] they want” is the object of “get,” “whenever they want” is an adverbial clause modifying “get,” and the clause “whomever they want” is the indirect object of “from.”